# Apache - How to redirect to a particular page in the httpd.conf file?

Tags: httpd, apache2

I'm trying to remove my .htaccess file, so that my Apache server no longer requires the .htaccess file.  As I have learnt it is something to avoid if possible.(https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)

I am trying to translate my redirect rules from the .htaccess to my httpd.conf, however when I use the following in my httpd.conf file, I end up with a 404 error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^contact$ maincontainpage.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^contactus/$ maincontainpage.html [NC]
```

How do I translate these redirection rules so that they are used in the httpd.conf file?

Any help on this would be greatly appreaciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server configuration equivalent for `.htaccess` is `<Directory>` context, having the exactly same matching for `RewriteRule`s. Used in other context the matching is different: within `<VirtualHost>` it starts with the leading `/` right after the hostname (and optional port), e.g.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^/contact$ maincontainpage.html [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/contactus/$ maincontainpage.html [NC]
```